# jQuery Datables - have up arrow sort largest first

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using Datatables 1.10, and would like the largest values be sorted when the user clicks the up arrow instead of when the user clicks the down arrow. How do I do this? I have tried using `orderSequence` and `order` attributes, but I can't get it to work. This is for the "salary" column.

https://jsfiddle.net/tcdotmn2/44/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`columns.orderSequence`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderSequence) to customize order sequence for each column.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/tcdotmn2/122/) for code and demonstration.

Sorting occurs when user clicks the heading, arrows are displayed only to indicate sorting order.